# MATCH Formula Returning 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following formula:

```
{=INDEX(config!H2:H20,MATCH(1,(F5=config!F2:F20)*(VLOOKUP(D5,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0)) }
```

I then wanted to add another condition to make sure that results were returned whereby the criteria matched the value **FALSE** in sheet: config, column: J

I used this formula:

```
{=INDEX(config!H2:H20,MATCH(1,(F5=config!F2:F20)*("FALSE"=config!J2:J20)*(VLOOKUP(D5,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0)) }
```

However, the formula just returns the value 0, even though the criteria can be matched.

Have I got the right syntax?

You can download here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb6kneeg42iwkvq/Book1%20-%20Editable.xlsm?dl=0

and look at sheet1 cell E5 for the new formula returning 0 and old formula is E4

Comment: Remove the `"` from around the `FALSE` it is a boolean expression not a string.

Comment: still the same... but it is a string isnt it?, coming from sheet config, column J

Comment: It appears to be a boolean,  But I do not down load workbooks from unknown sources so not positive.  `=1=1` will return a boolean. `=IF(1=1,"TRUE","FALSE")`  will return a string.

Comment: One way to check: the formula `ISTEXT()` will return `FALSE` on a Boolean